# How to set Classpath from terminal in Ubuntu to use Sun Java

Tags: java, classpath, javabeans

How do I run the http://www.jsptut.com/Forms.jsp . I am using Geany and I am not used to using java. The simple jsp's before this page were no problems.

Comment: You deploy a web app that includes the associated classes. Have you checked out any web app tutorials that discussed how they should be packaged/laid out?

Comment: I was following the tutorial mentioned in http://www.jsptut.com  and trying to keep up with it. What more do I need to do ? :-( sorry, I am not quite used to it.

Comment: You'd need to put the compiled classes, in their package structure, into the web container's `WEB-INF/classes` folder (or package your app in a war, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to set CLASSPATH for Java, you can find this post useful: https://justinalex.com/ubuntu-install-oracle-java-jdk-8/

It mainly involves editing the profile file based on two requirements:

- for all users, or
- for a single user